# Image issue not going to next column when resizing

Tags: html, css

New to programming and this one has been bugging me for quite a while. When resizing the browser, the image won't go onto next line, after the `.text` class but rather exceeds the page and goes right. Here's the relevant html and css:

```css
    main{
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }


    #image{
        height: 80vh;
        box-shadow: 8px 3px 10px gray;
        margin: 10px;
        border-radius: 1%;
    }

    .text{
        animation: fade-in;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        margin-left: 20px;
        padding-left: 40px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;

    @media screen and (max-width: 500px){
        .main{
            position: static;
            flex-direction: column;
            box-sizing: unset;
        }

        #image{
            display: block;
            position: static;        
        }
```

```html
 <main>
        <div class="text">
            <h1></h1>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <button </button>
            <button </button>
        </div>

        <img id="image" src="/images/image1.jpg" alt="">  
    </main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need > `flex-wrap: wrap` for `main` element. Because, by default, `display: flex` works the way it puts all it's child elements in one row, not allowing them to wrap until you specify that.

Also, for @media screen, you wrote .main and it should be just main, because it is not a class.

Answer (score 0):

In your media query, you have selected main tag by `.main` but it's not a class.
Please select it like this: `main {}`